# How can i do to get more solutions in my dictionary reading an csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am learning python from zero and find an exercise about reading balances in csv files.
In this code, that runs correctly, im getting a ratio from the last balance of that businesses, but now i want to know the balances for the last 2 years, not just the last year and if if put "print(screener[0:2]) i get the following error: "unhashable type: 'slice'"
How could i do to get the last 2 years of that ratio?
Thanks

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open("d:\\downloads\\balances.csv"), delimiter = ";")
        
balances = [fila for fila in data]

businesses = ["AAPL", "AMZN","FB","TSLA","KO","NFLX"]

calculate = {}

for business in businesses:

    calculate[business]=False
    
screener ={}

for balance in balances:

    business=balance[0]

    if business in businesses and balance[1]=="anual" and calculate[business]==False:

        try:
            screener[business]=round(int(balance[16])/int(balance[13]),2)
        except:
            screener[business]="couldnt calculate"
        finally:
            calculate[business]=True
print(screener)
```

Comment: Do you have the data for the last 2 years in your file ? In which columns do they appear ? Can you paste an example of the data ? You'll probably have to use the same formula you have but with different numbers than 16 or 13

Comment: I dont have the file right now. As soos as i get home (tomorrow morning) i will check everything u ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think WNG is already on top of helping you modify your code to get the balances you're looking for. I want to answer another (implicit) question in your post: why does `screener[0:2]` not work?

The only valid keys for dictionaries are immutable types. Thus, the tuple `(0,1,2)` is a valid dictionary key, but the list `[0,1,2]` is not. Wrapping mutable types in immutables also doesn't work:

```
>>> X = ([1,2], [3,4])
>>> d = {}
>>> d[X] = "a"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> Y = ((1,2), (3,4))
>>> d[Y] = "a"
>>> d
{((1, 2), (3, 4)): 'a'}
```

I'm not sure if slices are mutable or immutable, or if they have this property at all. I just learned that iterators are hashable:

```
>>> ten = range(10)
>>> d[ten] = "x"
>>> d
{((1, 2), (3, 4)): 'a', range(0, 10): 'x'}
```

As a final point, **there is no order to dictionary elements:** Because `screener` is a dictionary, you shouldn't think of the elements as existing in any specific order; they are only accessible by their key, e.g. `screener["AAPL"]` is valid, and `screener[0]` *could* be valid, since `int` is an immutable type, but it doesn't have to be the "first" element of the dictionary, it's just another key. Python handles how to store the data in a dictionary, and re-orders elements for efficient, (amoritized) constant-access time. Of course, computer memory has an order to it, since everything has a memory address and these increase sequentially, but if you run your code twice, the literal order the elements of `screener` are stored in memory can change.